# Microsoft equation editor adds undesired whitespace

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, updates, equation-editor

When I use the Microsoft equation editor, if I have a word that is greater than 10 characters in length, the equation editor automatically breaks the word and puts spaces in between them when the object is embedded in a powerpoint slide. For example-

If I have the word "automatically" in the equation editor, it shows up just fine when I am editing the text in the equation editor. But when I update this object to the powerpoint slide, it shows up as "automatica   lly". There is a tab or 5 spaces between "automcatica" and "lly". Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't noticed this, but try checking that you're writing text in text mode (style), that some parts of your words are not in the list of recognized mathematical functions ...

Comment: Well it happens to all words that are greater than 10 characters. Yes,  text mode is what I am using.

Comment: I have MS Powerpoint 2007 and Equation Editor 3.1. I checked and there's no problem. Which versions of Office and EE do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been frustrated with this problem as well, and found a way around it.  Instead of typing text in equation editor, try making a text box.  In Excel, this is done using the drawing toolbar (View -> Toolbars -> Drawing).  Leave a blank space in equation editor where you want to place your 10+ character word.  Then just place the text box over that space and there ya go.  You need to create the text boxes after creating the equation object for them to appear above the equation.

It's not really a solution to the problem, but after wasting over an hour trying to figure this out, it's the best I could come up with.  Good Luck!

Paul

Answer (score 2):

The key is the size of the text box. Eq Ed keeps expanding the box as you type and does not reduce the width of the box. When you are done and click outside of the box, all text styles are elongated. So, the solution is to reduce the width of the box as much as possible while in Eq Ed and before clicking on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Think I've figured out a work-around.  Type your equation (in Math style), then highlight the phrase you want to add spaces to, and select Text style.  Now add the spaces to your words.  Finally, highlight the correctly-spaced phrase again, and change the style back to Math.  The spaces will remain where you placed them, and it seems that the mysterious added spacing goes away.  Only issue is that your phrase will appear in italics now.